# Treeview control binding in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

This is an application for Dry-cleaning POS system . In the Booking form are groupboxes containing item buttons and a tree view where all the orders are dropped in and it takes this format.

```
2x Trouser (node)                  20 (Price)

     Blue   (Sub node)
     Cotton (Subnode)

1x Shirt      (node)               30 (Price)

     Black  (Sub node)
     Linen  (Sub node)

2x Shorts     (node)               30 (Price)

     Black  (Sub node)
     Linen  (Sub node)
     Press only(Sub node)         -15 (half of 30)
```

The above items are buttons grouped in group boxes. There is the group box for clothes, colors, materials and extra which are percentage based on cleaning amount like press only, re-clean etc.

When I click on a button in a particular group (say clothes or garment) the item is thrown into the treeview and its group disappears and the next group(color) is displayed and this goes on till I get to the last stage which is Extra and I then click on a next item button to start entering another clothe. This I can do, but here is my problem.

1. I don't know how to add the quantity figures beside the node items in the treeview
   (as you can see the first node which is trouser has a figure beside it, 2, the figure is meant to stand right beside the node items (Clothes) on the left side of the treeview but not as a node or subnode item
2. I don't know how to add the price figures opposite the node items in the treeview
   (As you can see the prices are not nodes nor subnode items they are meant to  stand separately to the far right in the treeview
3. I don't know how to bind each of these items (nodes and subnodes) to columns in a database table.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted what you're doing correctly, you're not going to be able to bind anything to the Treeview control.  You'll need to create procedures that will loop through your data and add nodes to the treeview accordingly.  I've added some rough code below that might help you.

In the past I have done this with two passes.  The first pass pulls and creates a datatable or reader of only top level nodes, in your case trousers, shirts, and shorts.  Loop through that set of data and add nodes to the TreeView.

```
Private Sub RefreshTopNodes()
        Dim dt As DataTable = TopNodes()
        For I As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            AddRootNode(dt.Rows(I).Item(0).ToString, dt.Rows(I).Item(1).ToString, dt.Rows(I).Item(2).ToString)
        Next
End Sub

Private Sub AddRootNode(NodeID As String, NodeDesc As String, Price As Integer)
        If NodeID = "ROOT" Then Exit Sub
        Dim tn As TreeNode = TreeQs.Nodes.Add(NodeID, NodeDesc & " (" & Price.ToString & ")", 0)
        tn.Tag = NodeID
End Sub
```

The second pass will pull and create a datatable or reader of sub nodes. Loop through that set add the sub nodes to the appropriate parent node.

```
Private Sub RefreshSubNodes()
        Dim dt As DataTable = SubNodes()
        For I As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            AddSubNode(dt.Rows(I).Item(0).ToString, dt.Rows(I).Item(1).ToString, dt.Rows(I).Item(2).ToString, dt.Rows(I).Item(3).ToString)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorHandler("frmADCMainPA.RefreshSubNodes", ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub AddSubNode(ParentNodeID As String, SubNodeID As String, SubNodeDesc As String, Price As Integer)
        Dim tn As TreeNode = TreeQs.Nodes(ParentNodeID).Nodes.Add(ParentNodeID & "-" & SubNodeID, SubNodeDesc & " (" & Price.ToString & ")")
        tn.Tag = ParentNodeID & ";" & SubNodeID
End Sub
```

I think for the quantities you can do this two ways.
1. Count as you loop through the subnodes and then go back to the parent node and edit the node's text to show the quantity.
2. Attach the subnode count to the parent node query and add to the quantity at the time you add the node.

From the information you gave these are my suggestions.